# Can My Web App Implement User Login and Remain Stateless?

Tags: web-applications, session, cookies, authentication

We have a web application that is stateless.  We are using http
authentication over SSL/TLS.  The user's browsers are
presumably storing authentication credentials (possibly even after a browser shut-down if they configure their browsers that way.)  We validate
them on every access.

For reasons mostly having to do with usability, we would like
to stop using http authentication.  Is there a reasonable way
to implement user login and

- Remain stateless.
- Not require users to re-type credentials on every access.
- Be at least as secure as http authentication over SSL/TLS.

For example, we are willing to use cookies, and could store the
username and password as a cookie.  However, this seems less
secure.  But is it?  If we use a non-persistent cookie, is it
less secure than whatever method a browser uses to store
credentials for the duration of the session, or longer?

We could store username and a hash of the password as suggested
here: [What should I store in cookies to implement "Remember me" during user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858448/) but is that
better?

We could store a random token as a cookie, but then we have to
keep a lookup table (session) on the server and become
stateful.

We could store an encrypted version of the credentials as a
cookie and then decrypt and validate on every access.  This
*seems* like it is slightly more secure than http
authentication and also does not require state.  However, I'm
not sure we want the additional overhead of decryption. And is it really more secure? If someone gets a copy of the encrypted (or hashed, as above) string, doesn't that give them the same access as if they had the password?

I'd appreciate your thoughts, but let's start with the
assumption that http authentication over SSL/TLS is secure
*enough* for our purposes and we want to stay stateless.

EDIT

After some more research, I think this stackoverflow question: [Client side sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131522/client-side-sessions) states the problem much better, and the answers are correspondingly better as well. Thanks to all for your input.

Comment: What software are you using as the server & database, as well as what language are you generating the pages with?

Comment: @sigint, the app is written in PHP on Apache. There is no database. Why does it matter?

Comment: If other (SO) users know what tools you have your disposal, they will try provide you with a solution that utilizes those tools.

Answer (score 1):

In a closed system (company intranets, or just a normal site but with a small, decently savvy crowd) validating by SSL-certificate would be preferable. Issue a certificate for every user, let them install it in their browsers, and you can revoke access for that certificate at any time (see for instance the ssl-cert identification system of myopenid.com(unfortunately buggy a.t.m.).

It would require some work on your users' part, and if that is not possible / desirable, a cookie-token would be far preferable, and whether you look up a user/passwd combo or a cookie token shouldn't make that much of a difference.

Comment: we do not have a closed system, so user-installed certificates are not an option. The difference I see between a cookie "token" (if we're talking about something random) and the user/password is that the token needs to be regenerated and stored on the server on each request. I don't have to update the user/password on the server on each request.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look into [PHP sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) as an alternative to cookies.

You can start a session with a single call to [`session_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

From there you can store whatever data you want about the user with the global `$_SESSION` array.

This doesn't take into account HOW you will authenticate users in the first place. That is usually done by looking up stored usernames / password hashes in a database.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see a random token as being more or less stateless than a username and password.

Both need to be looked up in some form of database. Your application already had state. The state of being authenticated or not authenticated.

The username and password that was being sent was exactly the same as a random token.

So my answer to your question is No. A web application cannot implement any form of user authentication and remain stateless.

Comment: I don't think the application has state. It does not store the state of "being authenticated or not authenticated" across requests. Each request is re-authenticated.

Comment: @bmb: Of course it is storing state. On the server is a database of who is authenticated which fetches the current state for every request.

Comment: if by state, you mean who has an account with us, then yes, we store that state. But we do not store a database of who is authenticated on one request that we read in a subsequent request. The subsequent request does a brand new authentication.

Comment: @bmb: And with a random token, for every request you would do a brand new authentication via token lookup. Same thing.